# Json Parsing in Rails 3 with MongoDB

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

**How to prevent Json parsing if the parameter is as json**

**Json String**

`"{\"Sat\":[\"22:0\",\"22:0\"],\"Thu\":[\"22:0\",\"22:0\"],\"Fri\":[\"22:0\",\"22:0\"],\"Tue\":[\"22:0\",\"22:0\"],\"Mon\":[\"22:0\",\"22:0\"],\"Wed\":[\"22:0\",\"22:0\"],\"Sun\":[\"22:0\",\"22:0\"]}"`

But i Need the solution for both json and json string,I'm using Rails 3 and MongoDB as a database.

**Json**

`{"Sat":["22:0","22:0"],"Thu":["22:0","22:0"],"Fri":["22:0","22:0"],"Tue":["22:0","22:0"],"Mon":["22:0","22:0"],"Wed":["22:0","22:0"],"Sun":["22:0","22:0"]}`

When i put the json string into `JSON.parse` it's give me the Json.
So,I face the problem in API for Android and iPhone

When the API is called from iPhone it's give me the proper Json,but when the same API called from Android it's give me a Json String.So, i need to **some smart code** for this, if it's json then no need to parse and when it's json string it's parse.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you control the input Json generator, whether to generate a string or an object?

Comment: I create it as a json object in android and pass as request parameter,but in rails controller it's type is string.